# Can I store a 1d array into a 2d array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I was coding midway when I find out that netbeans give me an error regarding the below code:

```
String [][]table={getRowArray()};
//getRowArray() will return me a 1D string array
```

Is there any way to store the 1D array returned by my method into the 2D array directly instead of using a for loop?
Thanks for any help rendered!

Comment: can give something like this-- String [][]table={getRowArray(), 0};

Comment: What is the return type of `getRowArray()`?

Comment: Return type is mentioned in the comment after array statement.

Comment: @Ravinder - What it returns and what it is declared to return can be two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters - yes, it is possible to do that.

```
public class Test {
    public String[] dum() {
        String[] x = {"Not sure"};
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        String[][] words = {t.dum()};
        System.out.println(words[0][0]); // prints "Not sure"
    }
}
```

Double  check the error you're getting.  Make certain that the return type of `getRowArray()` is truly `String[]`.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better solution for this, but I believe you need to specify a single index for one of the dimensions in order to store it, so you're storing the 1-d Array into a single index of the first-dimension.

i.e.

```
String [][]table;
table[0] = getRowArray();
```

this should work since the first dimension of the array stores other arrays

Comment: This almost works - but you'll need to initialize `table` first.

Comment: If this were to work (after initializing `table` so `table[0]` doesn't generate a NPE), then OP's original code would work. I suspect that the return type of `getRowArray()` is something other than `String[]`.

Comment: @TedHopp - OP clearly said `//getRowArray() will return me a 1D string array`

Comment: @Ravinder - It might return a 1D string array but still have return type `Object[]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String [] oneD = { "1", "2", "3", "4" }; // getRowArray();
String [][] twoD1 = { oneD };
String [] anotherOneD = null; // or filled
String [][] twoD2 = { oneD, anotherOneD };
String [][] twoD3 = new String[][] { oneD };
String [][] twoD4 = new String[][] { oneD, anotherOneD };
```